# NLP - Specific Text Extraction

Tags: nlp, text-extraction

I have to identify the country name from a random text. I have the country list.

I am struggling to find a solution that can train the model on the country list and when I provide a random text to that model as an input, it identifies the country name as an output.

eg:-

- "I live in India" will give "India"
- "London is the capital of United Kingdom" will give "United Kingdom"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really sounds like SpaCy

Answer (score 0):

In this case it seems you are matching text. Why would you need a model? Seems a little bit overkill.

If you have the country list, you should normalise the text

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normalizing-textual-data-with-python/

And then you could search for the countries in the text.

> https://www.dummies.com/programming/python/how-to-search-within-a-string-in-python/

You could use certain tecniques for matching such as levestein distance, but i don think it is necessary to build a model for this.

Comment: Hi miguelik, Actually I have put a very happy case as the examples. The text can also be like:

Country of LoadingIndiaPorts, Also their could be spelling mistakes like Indiia